# Scale real size defined objects before drawing?

Tags: android, matrix, scale

I.m trying to draw an array of objects, each object has its matrix:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
                MyObject o = obj[i];            
            canvas.drawBitmap(w.image, o.matrix, null);
        }
}
```

These are real world matrices and they need to scaled before drawing. For this reason I have another scale_matrix.
How if I concat o.matrix with scale_matrix the objects are properly repositioned, but the problem is that the images are also scaled and the quality is lost.
I don't want that because the images are already scaled to the right size for drawing.

One way to draw them at the right position is:

```
    float pts[] = {0, 0};            
    o.matrix.mapPoints(pts);
    scale_matrix.mapPoints(pts);
    canvas.drawBitmap(o.image, pts[0], pts[1], null);
```

but in this case they will be aligned and o.matrix transform will not be applied.

The question is how to use the scale_matrix to place the images at the right pixel positions and then apply o.matrix transform?

I want to use the scale_matrix to scale the space properly before drawing.

Comment: what if you concst them and setScale(1, 1) on the result?

Comment: I've tried, the result is they are all appear at (0,0)

Comment: I think all set methods actually overwrite the matrix.

Comment: yes it seems so, but what about setValues with both scales set to one?

Comment: Good! It seem to work this way. I still want to check some cases, and see if there is no better approach to this problem at all. Thank you.